# XAMPP - Apache is stuck on Attempting to start Apache service

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a windows 7 home premium operating system.  I have recently install xampp onto my computer with apache and mysql.  I opened xampp as administrator.   I attempted to start apache the following message occurs: Attempting to start Apache service .  I checked my ports and port 80 is not being used.  Skype is not running. I checked my event viewer to see my system logs and I found this: under general: The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 81 of C:/Apache/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_core.so into server: The specified module could not be found.     .
> > >       I know where the httpd config file exists, however I am sure what to edit to figure this problem out.  I am a bit of an amateur developer, though I understand most the concepts and components.  Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Thanks.